# Is it possible to see revivals using lowest order time evolution in Jaynes-Cummings

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I'm trying to implement Monte Carlo Wave Function method in the standard Jaynes-Cummings model

$$
H_{JC} = \frac{\Delta}{2}\sigma_z + a^\dagger a + g(\sigma_+ \otimes a + \sigma_- \otimes a^\dagger).
$$

Before opening the system, in the sense of eqn. (4) [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0805.4002.pdf), I am trying to test my program with $\gamma=0$. Essentially, I am applying eqn. (5) (of the ref.) at each time step:

$$
|\Psi(t+\delta t)\rangle = (1-\frac{iHt}{\hbar})|\Psi(t)\rangle,
$$

($\hbar=1$). I would like to cross-check my numerics by plotting the [atomic inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaynes%E2%80%93Cummings_model#/media/File:Collapseandrevival.png). To do so I need an initial coherent state in for the oscillator with photon number $25$, the atom is in the excited state and I chose $\Delta=1$, $g=1$ and I am taking steps of $0.001$.

I can recover the first oscillations, but the revivals at around $gt=20$ disapeear. Is this correct? How can you obtain such revivals using this method?